# form_for issue from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

Just wondering how i can get my form_for to render (it is located within another controller at the moment).

My form is located in the view `public/index` but the document needs to be created through `documents/new`

My error is

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

This is my form

```
<%= form_for @document, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

I have read various posts on here and have tried setting the url path using url:

```
<%= form_for @document, url: documents_new_path, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

routes.rb

```
put 'documents/new'
```

When i do

```
<%= form_for Document.new, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

Everything works, but I shouldn't have to do this should I

Could anyone point me in the direction of what I need to be looking at please

Edit

Controller

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @document = Document.new
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `@document` variable is not `nil` ?

Comment: I have read that this could be the issue but do not understand why it would be nil? how can i check this please?

Comment: In your controller, in action `new`, you should have a line something like `@document = Document.new`.

Comment: yes thats what i have

Comment: Could you elaborate on _it is located within another controller at the moment_ ?

Comment: Your controller action should initialize the document instance. It will work if you have form_for @document || Document.new. The variable defined in documents controller new action isnt being used as a request to public/index.html is not calling that controller action. You may also render the default page via a controller action and instantiate your document instance there.

Comment: thanks @AlokSwain that has helped , how would I setup your second pointer?

Comment: You can render public/index.html from a controller 
def index
  render :file => 'public/index.html' and return
end 
or define the root path in routes and rails will routes / to this path. Rails guides has this info in its Getting Started page and routing page(see the root path section here). Hope you find this helpful.